# Using AJAX with express (changing variables after request)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, pug

I want to make a single page app. simplification of what I want: First on `"/"` will be a home page with a display section with 2 buttons. when they click on button 1 we will retrieve data from server and display it on the page in the display section and do the same thing for button 2 but for different data.

I'm having a hard time grasping on how to put in the right display section.

I know you could do conditions in Jade like:

```
    html
    head
        script(src ="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js")
        script(src = "script.js")
    body
        p= test
        if test == "face"
            div.fillIn(style="background:blue; width:400; height:200")
        if age
            div.fillIn(style="background:red; width:400; height:200")
        button(value="send").send send

        button(value="change").change change
```

how do I put in the different variables for age and test? in the server I'm having trouble changing the variable after post request. should be trying to do that?

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var name;
var age;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static("public"))
app.set("view engine", "jade")

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    // if(age){
        res.render("index",{test: "fac", age: age })
    // }

})

//The server script that reads the paramater from the jQuery AJAX and returns the result
app.post("/some", function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body)
    age = req.body.age
    res.send(req.body.name + " and " +  req.body.age)
})
......
```

(I way I was thinking about doing it).I want to make it so that when the button is clicked it retrieves new data and it updates a variable so I could pass it along to Jade so it could update the proper display

button stuff in script.js

```
    $("button.send").on("click", function(){
        $.ajax({
            method : "POST",
            url : "/some",
            data : {name : Math.floor(Math.random() * 20), age :"42"},
            success : function(data){
                $(".fillIn").html(data)
            }
        })
```

EDIT:
 what I was thinking of doing was to have a 2 different AJAX calls for 2 different buttons each outputting 2 different data like above `data : {name : Math.floor(Math.random() * 20), age :"42"}` and the other one would be `data : {name : Math.floor(Math.random() * 20), age :"--->43<---"}`. what this does I think will in fill text in the `.fillin` div but I don't want to just fill in the div I want a whole other `fillin` div. One button will cause the div to have other specif text(HTML) that the user could read plus the data and the other button will do the same with other html element and that specific data. **I wish there was a way to pass in a template.** that's what I was trying to simulate by having 2 condition divs. I'm not trying to do something for a specific user at this point. I'm just thinking if I could do `data : {name : Math.floor(Math.random() * 20), age :"42 | 43"},` for both buttons. I'm passing a long data and I want to say which div to display.

Comment: I think you have some basic problems related to how (HTTP) requests and responses work. There are different types of requests (and responses) depending on what you want to do. For example, if you want to get something from the server, you do usually a GET request, if you want to upload something to the server, then you might need a POST or PUT requests. In general, you should not have too much logic on your template, in my opinion. When yo do a GET request, you might need to be more specific, for example you might want just to get data for a user.

Comment: In those cases, you need a way to identify the user, usually it's an ID, which might be stored as a property in the template or might be obtained by doing a "general" get request and by searching for it, or something similar... I don't understand very well your specific problem. Try to give me a feedback on what I have just said and depending on that I will try to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I edited the question for a response to your comment in case it got messy in the comment section. I hope it explains more of what I want. can you tell me why I can't do it?

Comment: Question: when I do  `data : {name : Math.floor(Math.random() * 20), age :"42"},`. does this saves the data to the URL or the server. you said that I'm uploading the data to the server when I use `post` so where is it being stored in the server. Is it in the `/some` url. I don't have a good understanding

Comment: Regarding this last question. You are doing a POST request (to the server) using AJAX to the route `/some`. In the server side, you need to have a route handler to POST requests to the route `/some`. There you will retrieve the data you are passing from the client-side, usually through the body of the request. But looking briefly at your code, it seems you have already that. It does not make sense IMO to say that the data is stored in the URL but to say that you are passing the data in the request to the server. The server is then responsible for doing whatever it wants with it.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't used JQuery yet, but only plain JS, so I don't understand fully the syntax, even if in general I understand it. Moreover, as I said, I haven't used Jade, but Dust.JS, so I am not sure how you can modify your template for your needs, if you even need to modify it. I hope someone else can help you :)