# Routing Express and outputting to template

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

lets say I have

```
router.get('/read', function(request, response) {
   res.send({"result": "Success sent from routes/index.js."});
});
```

how do I output a template with the data. If I use res.send() I can't use res.render() right?

If my users are at `/read` and click a button to send some data with ajax I want to display that data in another template on `/read`

Edit: One way to get around this is to make a string when you return the data (or maybe not)

```
        success : function(data){
            $(".fillIn").html("<p style = 'color:green;'>" + data + "</p>")
        }
```

I don't want a string.

The pic shows that on one page "/"  there are 2 buttons and by clicking each button you can send data and that data can be displayed on the right depending on which button was clicked, a form with some data filled in or a table filled in with some data. I use ajax to send the data on click..There will be different forms with different styles. That's why I want to add in a template. I could do that with HTML using .load() I think but I cant figure out how do with that jade.

Here's my other [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711376/using-ajax-with-express-changing-variables-after-request?noredirect=1#comment57170983_34711376)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your index.js file, use the following to capture GET and POST requests and render different responses:

```
app.get('/read', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('emptyFormTemplate');
});

app.post('/read', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('dataTableTemplate', {
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email
    });
});
```

On the client-side, you you can something like this to POST the data to /read. You would include this script in `emptyFormTemplate` in the above example.

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(event){
    var formData = {
        'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
        'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/read',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't know I could use res.render() in a POST handler. I'm getting closer but as of right now I'm experiencing a problem. when I click the button I see `
POST http://localhost:3000/read 200 OK 60ms` and in the response in the console I see the value in the response  but the page isn't changing.("/read") It stays the same as `emptyFormTemplate.jade"` I think

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's a bit difficult to troubleshoot - could you create a Jsfiddle or Plunker?